How to document the working/root directory in Doxgen?
In Doxygen one can use the \dir command to document directories. I often create README.md files in directories containing
\dir .
\brief Dir contains code (may contain bugs)

But how to write a documentation entry for the root directory of the project?
I have tried a file /README.md with the commands as shown above. As alternative /misc/README.md with \dir .. Both did not create a documentation entry for the directory itself.
I don't want to use absolute paths as the command's argument as this would not be portable.
example
This is a minimal example:
doxygen_root_directory_test/
├── dir_a
│   ├── a.h
│   └── README.md
├── Doxyfile
├── README.md
└── r.h

The *.h files are empty.

doxygen_root_directory_test/Doxyfile:
RECURSIVE=YES


doxygen_root_directory_test/README.md:
\dir .
\brief root directory


doxygen_root_directory_test/dir_a/README.md:
\dir .
\brief directory a



In this case the "root directory" is doxygen_root_directory_test.
I execute doxygen from within that directory:
~/doxygen_root_directory_test$ doxygen -q
~/doxygen_root_directory_test/README.md:1: warning: No matching directory found for command \dir ~/doxygen_root_directory_test/

Note that I have replaced the path to the parent directory of the root directory with ~.
I am using doxygen version 1.10.0 (ebc57c6dd303a980bd19dd74b8b61c8f3f5180ca).
output
Within the 'File List' (html/files.html) I would expect an entry for the root directory (. or "root" or ... ). Similar to the one for dir_a:

Also an equivalent to the directory reference for dir_a:

How can I get directory reference entries for the root directory? As for dir_a above. Without writing absolute paths in the files.

Which version of doxygen are you using. What do you mean with the "root directory of your project"? Can you give a small example project (including the used doxygen settings different from the default doxygen settings, i.e. the result of doxygen -d Doxyfile). Where do you want to show the doxumentation of the "root directory" in the result?

@albert I added more details. Please let me know if some information is missing. Thank you for considering my question.

So actually you would like to see an extra directory on top, what is there against to go to the parent (..) directory of doxygen_root_directory_test, giving here the command doxygen doxygen_root_directory_test/Doxyfile and having in the Doxyfile the entries INPUT=doxygen_root_directory_test and OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=doxygen_root_directory_test?

Or just set STRIP_FROM_PATH = <your_path>/doxygen_root_directory_test/..

@albert this is what I have been looking for! It did not occur to me that STRIP_FROM_PATH could be useful as the absolute path is not explicitly written in the files. I guess doxygen finds \dir ., then replaces . with the absolute path of the directory and applies then STRIP_FROM_PATH.
Also valid is: STRIP_FROM_PATH = .. which I prefer as it is more generic.
Would you please post an answer from your comment? Then I can mark this question as answered.

Configure STRIP_FROM_PATH = ... Then one can document the root directory using
\dir .

In an input file within the root directory.
This answer is based on albert's comment.
